# Save result to variable?

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I have been developing a note taking app, and I am having some trouble with displaying the username! Normally you would get a result like this:

```js
con.query('SELECT someVariable FROM someColumn', function (result)  {
  console.log(result)
})
```

But I would like to save the result to a variable like this:

```js
var variable = ''; 
con.query('SELECT someVariable FROM someColumn', function (result)  {
  variable = result
}) 
console.log("Here is some data: " + variable)
```

But that obviously wouldn't work. So how can I do this???

## The point

How would I save a mySQL `result` to a variable, so it can be used later in my code? Also Im not an experienced developer so you might have to do a bit more explaining that usual, thanks.

Comment: Tip: [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/) makes this super easy.

Comment: Voting to close - duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Node and/or JavaScript then you've just stumbled on one of the major problems of asynchronous programming. Here's your code as the JavaScript runtime sees it:

```js
// Declare variable

var variable = '';

var callback = function(result) {
  variable = result;
};

// This code runs right away
con.query('SELECT someVariable FROM someColumn', callback);

// Then this code runs
console.log("Here is some data: " + variable);

// Then, a thousand years later (from a CPU's perspective) this callback executes
callback(result);
```

You can see you're jumping the gun here. You can't depend on any behaviour *until the callback has run*, or in other words, you need to put any dependent behaviour *inside the callback*.

Since it's 2020 you can also do this with `async` and `await` if you're using a Promise-capable library. Your code could look like:

```js
// Assign variable to the result of the query call, waiting as long as necessary
let variable = await con.query('SELECT someVariable FROM someColumn');

console.log("Here is some data: " + variable);
```

This *will* be properly sequenced.